# call global function with input from Webpack 4 in html

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I want to add window name to top of webpack file like

```
"window["webpackTest"] =
/******/ (function(modules) "
```

then I want to call my init function with passing parameters in js file. I added some feature to webpack configuration file

```
globalObject: 'this',
library: 'myLib',
libraryTarget: 'var'
```

and I can see top of my webpack js file

```
var myLib = /******/
(function(modules) {
```

I wonder, how can I call my function in html file.

Comment: why `window.webpackTest` won't work?

Comment: I couldn't create window.webpackTest. it created var myLib = (function(modules)). That's why asked

Comment: Ah you need webpack external configuration for that. I’ll write an answer later when I’m near my computer